# Can Sysprep be used to generalize a clone (as opposed to the master)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clone, sysprep

My company has 200 PCs that were cloned from one master PC without using Sysprep. (We didn't know we should use Sysprep at the time we cloned them.) We have experienced occasional "domain trust relationship" errors with these cloned PCs. Going forward we plan to use Sysprep on all cloned PCs. However, now we are trying to determine what to do about these 200 PCs that were cloned without Sysprep. I ran Sysprep on one of these 200 improperly cloned PCs, and after restarting and running through the Windows setup, the PC seems to work fine. But I am not sure if this will cause unforeseen problems down the road for this PC. I don't even know if it "fixed" the problem that was causing the "domain trust relationship" errors, since this error rarely occurs and I do not know how to simulate the conditions that cause it to occur.

Is running Sysprep on the clone (instead of on the master) going to produce a properly functioning PC? Or are we asking for trouble? Anyone have any experience with doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always hate to answer my own question, but since I did find a definitive answer, I thought it was best to post it..

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx) Microsoft says:

> You must not use Sysprep to reconfigure an existing installation of Windows that has already been deployed. Use Sysprep only to configure new installations of Windows.

Since Sysprepping an already cloned machine is not supported by Microsoft, I consider it a bad idea and will not do so. It appears as if re-imaging all 200 PCs is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using sysprep in that fashion should work.  Most of your issues are stemming from non-unique machine SIDs.